How can I end an anonymous Lichess game without resigning?
I started an anonymous correspondence game with a friend (i.e. I am signed in but they were not). My friend lost access to the game and it is configured with unlimited time. The only way I can see to get the game out of my "games in play" section is to resign.
How can I remove the game so that it won't show up in my game history at all or at least not influence my profile statistics?

Is Lichess really a game? Shouldn't this be on the Chess Stack Exchange?

@SuperByte It seems that it fits the definition of a video game. But if you want to discuss this, you should make a post on [meta].

According to bufferunderrun, an official Lichess moderator:

Players in "Unlimited" games have 3 weeks to make a move. So they'll timeout in a few weeks.

See: https://lichess.org/forum/general-chess-discussion/my-anonymous-opponent-left-the-game-and-it-left-me-waiting-for-opponent-forever#2
Link to moderator's profile: https://lichess.org/@/bufferunderrun

To anyone else coming here with the same problem: It has been 4 weeks and the game has not ended. It could be because the moderator in the link was implying that casual games won't end on their own.
